# Most efficient way to split character array into cells?

Tags: matlab

I'm currently working on rewriting one of my older data processing functions and I have an optimization question. The main purpose of the function is to process & compile up to 39 columns of 1000Hz DAQ data from a *.csv file, so I'm dealing with a fairly large amount of data.

The original function was 'dumb' to the number of lines in the file and simply concatenated the data chunks read in by `textscan` with the existing array.

Example pseudocode:

```
some_variable = [] % initialize
while ~feof(fid)
    segarray = textscan(fid, format, chunk_size, 'Delimiter',',');
    some_variable = [some_variable segarray{:,1}];
end
```

Painfully inefficient but when I wrote it I didn't know any better.

Anyway, my new function leverages a quick couple lines of Perl (found [over at the MATLAB Newsgroup](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/235126), I primarily work on Windows) to count the number of lines so I can intelligently initialize all of my data arrays.

This has given me a significant increase in speed but uncovered a couple implementation issues, one of which is the one I'd like to ask about. A few of the columns are single character fields (`%c` in the `textscan` format spec) that `textscan` concatenates into a single character array on its output. So for a chunk size of 5000, the output from `textscan` in that column is a `5000x1` character array (with no delimiter). I'd like to split this into a `5000x1` cell array but I'm not sure what the most efficient way to do this is.

The line I came up with utilized `mat2cell`: `some_variable = mat2cell(segarray{:,1},ones(length(segarray{:,1}),1),1)`, which works fine, but is there a faster method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll check the code for `mat2cell`:

```
edit mat2cell  % at Command window
```

you'll see that it is trivially implemented: allocates the cell array according to dimensions, then fills in the cells with the "sliced" input in a `for` loop.

This suggests to make an analogous "special" function that deals only with this:

```
function C = str2cell(S)
    N = numel(S);
    C = cell(N, 1);
    for k = 1:N
        C{k} = S(k);
    end;
end
```

I can't imagine something faster than this... and, contrary to the common wisdom, `for` loops are quite fast in the last versions of MATLAB.

Please note that if your `S` parameter is a 2D matrix, the function will "unwind" it to a row cell array output.

Comment: Oh, duh. I didn't even think to look at `mat2cell` to see what it was doing. This was my first thought, I wasn't sure if there was a better method. Thank you!